How to append a document/object to an existing bson_t array using libbson C API
I have a JSON string I know it is a JSON object e.g.
char* jsonObjStr = "{ \"Name\" : \"Obj_1\" }";

and another JSON string I know it is a JSON array e.g.
char* jsonArrayStr = "[ { \"Name\" : \"Obj_0\" } ]";

I would like to get the bson_t struct associated with appending the json obj to the array. I can get bson_t* structs for both strings by using bson_new_from_json(). So I can have:
bson_t* bsonObj = bson_new_from_json((const uint8_t*) jsonObjStr, -1, NULL);
bson_t* bsonArray = bson_new_from_json((const uint8_t*) jsonArrayStr, -1, NULL);

But I can not use
bson_append_document(bsonArray, bsonObj); 

to directly append the obj to the array, because it needs a key, so it won't append it as a new array entry but as a named field ...
The only way to append to the array is to use bson_array_builder_xxx however bab API does not allow to init the bab with the original array data (there is no bson_array_builder_new_from_json() or bson_array_builder_new_from_data() type of functions).
The only way I can think of is to start with an empty bab, iterate the existing bson_t* bsonArray and add each element one by one to the bab, and finally appending the desired bson_t* bsonObj but I find this very inefficient.
I tried using bson_concat() by wrapping bsonObj to a bab with only one element, build the bab to a bson_t (babWrapOneElemArray) and then calling
bson_concat(bsonArray, babWrapOneElemArray);

This seemed to work but I got into some issues later on, so I am guessing this workaround is not the right way to do this. Am I missing something? Can anyone help?

Arrays don't really exist in BSON.  From bsonspec.org: Array - The document for an array is a normal BSON document with integer values for the keys, starting with 0 and continuing sequentially. For example, the array ['red', 'blue'] would be encoded as the document {'0': 'red', '1': 'blue'}. The keys must be in ascending numerical order.

Thanks to Joe for his comment: use numKeys = bson_num_keys(bsonArray) to get the number of keys (entries), and use bson_append_document(bsonArray, "numKeys", -1, bsonObj)
